# How to target parent of a hyperlink in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="product">
Content In Here
  <div class="price">
   <a href="#" class="removeLink">Remove</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to target the parent of the remove link like this:

```
$('.removeLink').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent('.product').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

However for some reason it's not working and I can't figure out why, there is no error messages in the Javascript console, any idea why it won't fade out the parent .product div?

Comment: some jsfiddle would be nice...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `parents()`, not the singular:

```
$('.removeLink').click(function(event) { 
      event.preventDefault(); 
  $(this).parents('.product').fadeOut('fast'); 
});
```

Comment: Yeah looks like parent only goes up one div / element

Answer (score 2):

You want `$(this).closest('.product')`, which looks for the nearest item up the DOM tree that matches `.product`. The way `.parent` works is to select the item's parent (in this case, `<div class="price">`), and then apply the filter you've specified. I.e., what you're realling saying is, "select the parent if the parent matches `.product`," which is clearly not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `closest()` method

```
$('.removeLink').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.product').fadeOut('fast');
});​
```

Working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Pyxnm/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.removeLink').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut();
  });

});
```

​
so here you hide the godfather and his children
take a look at the code here
[jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/TVUjg/2/)